# Targeting li elements except when preceded by a non li element

Tags: jquery, html, css

How can I target the li elements except when they come after the `<p class="Notes>` element? In other words, I want to target the Steps but not the Notes.

I tried adding a class to the OL that I want to exclude from selection but the code I came up with doesn't work.

(Btw, restructuring the html is not an option)

```
('#a > ol > li.P-List-number').not(':has("ul.Notes")')


<div id="a">
<h2 class="task">Blah, blah, blah</h2>
    <p class="Body">Yada, yada, yada:</p>
        <ol>
          <li class="P-List-number">Step 1...</li>
          <li class="P-List-number">Step 2...</li>
          <li class="P-List-number">Step 3...</li>
       </ol>
       <p class="Notes>NOTES</p>
       <ol class="Notes">
          <li class="P-List-number">Note 1</li>
          <li class="P-List-number">Note 2</li>
       </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: You have a typo in `<p class="Notes>`. Also, `#a > ol` won't work as the ol isn't a child of #a. And `p.Body + ol > li.P-List-number` should work.

Comment: Your whole attempt makes little sense from start to finish. Your list item parents don’t have any class, yet you are trying to select them by not having a specific class. And they aren’t `ul` either, they are `ol`. / Go look up the adjacent sibling combinator.

Comment: this is some fugly code, you got there. but except that, your not selector.. why are you writing `ul.Notes`, when it is `ol`..? simply write `.not('.Notes')`... and yeah, the chain of siblings is messed up, too..

Answer (score 1):

You can use `p:not(.Notes)` and then select `ol` with `next()` and li with `children()`

```js
$('p:not(.Notes)').next('ol').children('li').css('color', 'blue');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a">
  <h2 class="task">Blah, blah, blah</h2>
  <p class="Body">Yada, yada, yada:</p>
  <ol>
    <li class="P-List-number">Step 1...</li>
    <li class="P-List-number">Step 2...</li>
    <li class="P-List-number">Step 3...</li>
  </ol>
  <p class="Notes">NOTES</p>
  <ol class="Notes">
    <li class="P-List-number">Note 1</li>
    <li class="P-List-number">Note 2</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Or just `p:not(.Notes) + ol li`

```js
$('p:not(.Notes) + ol li').css('color', 'blue');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="a">
  <h2 class="task">Blah, blah, blah</h2>
  <p class="Body">Yada, yada, yada:</p>
  <ol>
    <li class="P-List-number">Step 1...</li>
    <li class="P-List-number">Step 2...</li>
    <li class="P-List-number">Step 3...</li>
  </ol>
  <p class="Notes">NOTES</p>
  <ol class="Notes">
    <li class="P-List-number">Note 1</li>
    <li class="P-List-number">Note 2</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: $('#a > ol > li.P-List-number').not(':has(".Notes") + ol li')